# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: c#, sql

Please help me as I'm beginner here i'm updating the employee record by selecting from datagridview where I'm confused on gender field with two radio buttons and 3 date fields dob, doj & doexpid, I don't know how to write a code under `dg1_CellClick` and when ever I'm executing the code

> "incorrect syntax near the keyword `WHERE`"

```
private void dg1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    txtempcode.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtfrstname.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txtlstname.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    if (male.Checked || female.Checked)
    {
        dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    }
    txtaddr.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    txtcont.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    txtblodgrp.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    txtcountry.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    combobranch.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    txtnetsalary.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
    combodesig.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
    txtqibacc.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
    txtremark.Text = dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[15].Value.ToString();

    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT empimage FROM employee WHERE empcode = '" + dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", cn );
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    byte[] mydata = new byte[0];
    da.Fill(ds, "employee");
    DataRow myrow;
    myrow = ds.Tables["employee"].Rows[0];
    mydata = (byte[])myrow["empimage"];
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
    pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
    cn.Close();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();
    int i = 0;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employee SET empcode = '" + txtempcode.Text + "', firstname = '" + txtfrstname.Text + "', lastname = '" + txtlstname.Text + "', gender = @gender, address = '" + txtaddr.Text + "', contactno = '" + txtcont.Text + "' , bloodgroup = '" + txtblodgrp.Text + "' , dateofbirth = '" + dob.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' , country = '" + txtcountry.Text + "' , department = '" + combobranch.Text + "', basic_sal = '" + txtnetsalary.Text + "' , designation = '" + combodesig.Text + "' , doj = '" +doj.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "', doexpid = '" + doexpqid.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "' , pf_acc_no = '" + txtqibacc.Text + "' , remarks = '" + txtremark.Text + "', @empimage WHERE empcode = '" + dg1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", cn);
        if (male.Checked)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@gender", "male"));
    else
        //if (female.Checked)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@gender", "Female"));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empimage", pic);

    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (i > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated Employee Record" + i);
    }
    cn.Close();
```

Comment: You have a syntax error just before the WHERE clause _,@empimage WHERE..._ missing the name of the field that should receive the @empimage parameter. But, now stop here and read all you can about [PARAMETERIZED QUERIES](http://www.bing.com/search?q=PARAMETERIZED%20QUERIES&qs=n&sk=&sc=8-21&form=BDKTKB&pc=BDT5&shash=&BDParam=2000&mkt=en-US)

Comment: use the debugger to evaluate the values and make sure they are not null have you stepped through the code..?

Comment: What appens if male or female are checked? LOL

Comment: I would research "C# Layers"  Like this one ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx )  You've mixed way too many concerns here.  I know you're a beginner, but better to get started on the right foot.

Comment: @T-moty I wonder what other options there were

Answer (score 3):

If you remove this `@empimage` before the WHERE, then your query will work as it would be expected.

However, I strongly suggest you rewrite this query with parameters. Doing so, you will gain both in security (avoiding a sql injection) and readability.